# FluentValidation not rejecting requests automatically on invalid model state

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Validators are all placed in the same project (with the `Startup.cs`).

Code form `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(s =>
    {
        s.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
    });
```

ModelState.IsValid property actually turns false, when request data does not meet validator-set rules, but I need actual validator error messages set manually.

Validator itself:

```
public class UserRegistrationRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterUserRequest>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UserRegistrationRequestValidator"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public UserRegistrationRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(u => u.Email)
            .Matches("^[\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}$")
            .WithMessage(RegistrationRequestValidatorMessages.WrongEmailFormat);
        RuleFor(u => u.Password)
            .Matches("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$")
            .WithMessage(RegistrationRequestValidatorMessages.PasswordFormatNotValid);

        RuleFor(u => u.FirstName)
            .Matches("^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$")
            .WithMessage(RegistrationRequestValidatorMessages.FirstNameWrongFormat);

        RuleFor(u => u.LastName)
            .Matches("^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$")
            .WithMessage(RegistrationRequestValidatorMessages.LastNameWrongFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I need actual validator error messages set manually_ - can you add some detail about what you want to do?

Comment: @stuartd. you can specify custom error messages when building rules in the validator constructor. So that they are returned as a response and you can actually see, what data is wrong

Comment: Can you add an example of _how_ you tried to do that? We are using this feature in our project and it's working fine ...

Comment: Do you unit test the validators to see if you are actually getting expected custom messages?

Comment: @Fildor, I have recently been working on a similar project where I used FluentValidation the same way and when testing the API with swagger, I could clearly see the error messages I set in the constructor using .WithMessage() method. Added the validator code.

Comment: I simply should get status code 400 with the error messages I set in the validator when my request is not valid, but instead I get 204 (as if everything is fine)

Comment: Sounds like the Validators are not picked up by DI... I see nothing wrong with the implementation of the Validator.

Comment: Maybe set a breakpoint and see if it gets hit.

Comment: @Fildor, I have tried setting a breakpoint inside the validator and yes, it hit the constructor.

Comment: Ok, so it's picked up. Then next step would be to write a Unit Test and see if the Validator actually trips on the input data.

Comment: @Fildor, well, I did that. Validate() returns validation result with the messages I provided. But I still don't understand why validator does not abort invalid requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I forgot to mark my AuthenticationController with `[ApiController]` and `[Route]` attributes.